# Django -- Teacher Student advice?

Tags: python, django, models

I am new to Django and trying to set up models for a teacher to student relationship. Both the teacher and the student will have access to course material for any given course. The teacher will have many students in a course, and each student will have many teachers (depending on how many courses they are taking). I have this set up right now: Am I on the right track?

```
class CourseWare(models.Model):
    #information goes here?
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor)
    TrainingManager = models.ForeignKey(TrainingManager)

class Instructor(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(courseWare) #instructor deals with one course
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u's_' + self.firstName + u' ' + self.lastName

class Student(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True,null=True)
    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(Instructor) #Many Instructors <-> Many Students?
    material = models.ForeignKey(CourseWare)
    terminationDate = models.DateField()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "am I doing this right?" questions belong on [codereview.se].

Comment: @MattBall only if this code is **tested and working**

Comment: @MattBall I didn't know that was a thing. I see questions like this here all the time; genuinely don't know if I'm structuring my code correctly.

Comment: @plesh Is your code doing as you intend? If it is, then codereview can help improve it and give you advice on how to approach it better (ie. more cleanly, in a more readable way, etc.). If your code isn't behaving as intended, then this is the right place to ask. But in the latter case, please explain how it's not working for you.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Where is your `Student` model? Where is your `Course` model? Your code seems to deviate significantly from your description.

Comment: @Blender in this case Client==Student. Sorry, I wasn't more clear. The CourseWare class represents course material.

Answer (score 1):

Since your instructors can teach only one course, I would do something like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    instructor = models.OneToOneField(Instructor, related_name='course')
    training_manager = models.ForeignKey(TrainingManager)

    students = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name='courses')

class Instructor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    termination_date = models.DateField()
```

The `related_name` keyword argument lets you query things in reverse. For example, `some_student.courses.all()`.

Comment: hmmm, okay that makes sense. Is it unnecessary to create the attributes relating student to instructor? i.e. instructors = models.ManyToManyField(Instructor) as part of the student class?